# IdleStateHandler in Netty 4?

Tags: netty

I have it added to my pipeline and the LoggingHandler is catching its events but since the event system changed from Netty 3 to 4 how do I handle these events seeing as IdleStateAwareUpstreamHandler no longer exists?

LoggingHandler:
Dec 31, 2012 5:46:19 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler
INFO: [id: 0xfef88037, /127.0.0.1:63531 => /127.0.0.1:7633] USER_EVENT: WRITER_IDLE(0, 30001ms)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, make sure that your pipeline has an `IdleStateHandler` and the handler which wants to get notified on `IdleStateEvent` is placed after the `IdleStateHandler`.

`ChannelStateHandler` and `ChannelInboundHandler` has an event handler method called `userEventTriggered()`.  You can implement that method like the following:

```
@Override
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) {
    if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this event triggered? In the sense how can we configure the delay at which this should be trigered?

Comment: Is IdleStateHandler what you want? http://static.netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html

Comment: Edited to answer @Abe 's question.